# How to visualize TF-IDF terms?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, tf-idf

I have a few thousands of rows of textual data. My sample data is:

[image]

I have used sklearn CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer I calculated top terms with tfidf weights. Below is the code which I used for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
data = pd.read_csv('Sample_data.csv')
cvec = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', min_df=5, max_df=0.95, ngram_range=(1,2))
cvec.fit(data['Text'])
list(islice(cvec.vocabulary_.items(), 30))
len(cvec.vocabulary_)
cvec_count = cvec.transform(data['Text'])
print('Sparse Matrix Shape : ', cvec_count.shape)
print('Non Zero Count : ', cvec_count.nnz)
print('sparsity: %.2f%%' % (100.0 * cvec_count.nnz / (cvec_count.shape[0] * cvec_count.shape[1])))

occ = np.asarray(cvec_count.sum(axis=0)).ravel().tolist()
count_df = pd.DataFrame({'term': cvec.get_feature_names(), 'occurrences' : occ})
term_freq = count_df.sort_values(by='occurrences', ascending=False).head(30)
print(term_freq)
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
transformed_weights = transformer.fit_transform(cvec_count)
weights = np.asarray(transformed_weights.mean(axis=0)).ravel().tolist()
weight_df = pd.DataFrame({'term' : cvec.get_feature_names(), 'weight' : weights})
tf_idf = weight_df.sort_values(by='weight', ascending=False).head(30)
print(tf_idf)
```

Now I want to plot (bar or line graph) the top 30 terms with their weights using matplotlib. How can I do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: please provide a sample of `Sample_data.csv` so we can run your code

Comment: @anon01 I have included sample data as requested.